# Remove duplicates from a List(Of T) in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

I fail to remove duplicates from my List.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim Contacts As New List(Of Person)

...

' remove duplicates '
Contacts = Contacts.Distinct(New PersonEqualityComparer).ToList
```

my equality comparer:

```
Public Class PersonEqualityComparer
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Person)
    Public Function Equals1(ByVal x As Person, ByVal y As Person) As Boolean Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of Person).Equals
        Return String.Equals(x.EmailAddress, y.EmailAddress, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) AndAlso _
               String.Equals(x.GivenName, y.GivenName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) AndAlso _
               String.Equals(x.Surname, y.Surname, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    End Function
    Public Function GetHashCode1(ByVal obj As Person) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of Person).GetHashCode
        Return obj.GetHashCode
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement `GetHashCode1` so that any two equal objects have the same hashcode.

If many unequal objects have the same hashcode, it will perform much more slowly, especially for large lists.  In other words, don't change it to `Return 0`.

In your case, the simplest implementation would be like this:

```
Return StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(obj.EmailAddress) _
   Xor StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(obj.GivenName) _
   Xor StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(obj.Surname)
```

If you want a more robust implementation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overriden-in-c/371348#371348).

Comment: I didn't notice that you're comparing case insensitively.  You **must** use my updated answer; the original was case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb as New StringBuilder
...concatenate all strings...
return StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(sb.ToString())
```

It is certainly slower than the *xor* method or rolling your own proper hash function.
You may try to use this however, if you have high collision rates because of xoring.